# error: C2248: 'QVariant::QVariant' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QVariant'

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I get an unexpected error at the following line:

```
MyClass * myObject = new MyClass;

view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myObject", myObject);
```

with error:

```
error: C2248: 'QVariant::QVariant' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QVariant'
```

But `MyClass` is just a class I wrote and it doesn't do anything in particular with `QVariant` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was I forgot to derive `MyClass` from `QObject`. It needs to be derived and `Q_OBJECT` macro defined in it just like for any `QObject` derived class.

Comment: Or, use the right method (the factory builder): `QVariant::fromValue(...)`